# How to preserve timezone offset when posting a JavaScript date object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

From my AngularJS web app I'm posting a date to the server using $http.post. On the server side I would like to get the date's local representation but this isn't possible since the timezone isn't preserved when the `Date` object is serialized. This is what goes over the wire: `{startTime: "2015-03-04T11:00:00.000Z"}` but what I really want is `{startTime: "2015-03-04T12:00:00.000+01:00"}`.
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: How are you doing the serialization?

Comment: I'm not. I guess AngularJS is doing the serialization or whatever is underneath.

Comment: Can you show your `$http.post` call so that the answers can show you how to integrate the solutions into your existing code?

Comment: Well it's nothing fancier than: `$http.post(endPointUrl, timeObject)` so I'll just need to add a separate parameter for the offset to the payload, in accordance with the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the timezone offset as a separate param.

Comment: I believe it does answer the question. There are other things the OP needs to accomplish server-side to get the date in the format he would want after passing the data to the server. However, based on my research, it is not possible to get JS to pass the date to the server in the format he wishes. Hence, he will need to pass the timezone separately. If I am wrong about this, I would love to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to post as a complement parameter the timezone offset

```
var d =  new Date(mydate);
var timezone = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: This works well when the offset is the same as the local offset. But what if it's not? How do I handle sitting in Sweden (UTC+1) and handling EST time (UTC-5)?

Comment: The same way. `d.getTimezoneOffset()` will return `60` or `-300`

Answer (score 0):

Pass time zone offset `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();` as seperate parameter and rendered it on server side accordingly.